# CollectionView GridItemsLayout for UWP fails to work on the publish app, what could be the work around except using customized Grid View?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
 <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
     <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" />
  </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

The above xaml layout works on the debug and release mode but crashes on the publish app. How can I resolve this issue except using customized Grid View?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to update xamarin form  to latest version?

Comment: Yes. The version I currently use is 4.7.0.968 for both Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Form.Maps. And I switched to the latest one 4.7.0.1239, still fail for UWP running on Windows mode. It runs okay on Debug and Release Mode in Visual Studio. However, when you run directly on the Windows after building in Release mode, it fails.

Comment: Could  you share us with [mcve]?

Comment: I tried a new small minimal reproducible example as you mentioned and it is working fine. Thank you so much. However, I still confused why is happening on the one in my real app. The only different is I use await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(payments), the payments is a bindable properties in the pop up view and is bound to the PopupView's CollectionView's ItemsSource. I guess it is because the Bindable Properties are created before the payments pass to the PopupView. Thus the app crashes.

Comment: Yep, please try edit your mentioned part to exclude the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much Nico. The issue has been resolved since I created a custom grid instead of using CollectionView.

Comment: Cool, please feel free post your answer below and mark yourself.

Comment: I just put my code to the [link](https://github.com/Revfeng/ReplaceCollectionViewWithGrid). The custom grid view will act the same as using CollectionView's GridItemsLayout api. Thank you Nico for the help.